# Problem related to countability of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ the set of all natural numbers is finite or infinite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The set of all finite subsets of the natural numbers is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908222/the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-the-natural-numbers-is-countable)

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: See also [Show that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200389)  and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/200389).

Answer (score 1):

The following are all examples of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$:

$\{0\}, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\ldots$

Comment: I agree but this doesn't answers my question.

Comment: Actually, it does answer your question.

Comment: @anubhavtiwari Is $\Bbb N$ infinite or finite?

Comment: Got u I wanted to ask weather that set is countable or uncountable.